# How to connect a prototype cell in storyboard to a cell created programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I have the cells for a UITableView outlined programmatically.  Labels, positioning, etc...  In order to drag a segue to a different view, I need to see some visual representation of a prototype cell in storyboard.  How do I proceed?

What I have tried is to drag a prototype cell onto my UITableView.  I changed "Identifier" to my reuse cell identifier which was set in code.  After this, I proceeded to link up the prototype cell by right dragging to the destination view, selecting modal, etc...  When I run the app, nothing happens after I tap on a cell.

What would the best method be to link up an entirely coded cell with a visual depiction in storyboard?

Not sure what code to paste here, or if it's even necessary since I'm asking for generic information.  Please let me know if and what I should include for example.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"alertDetail"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPathA = [[self.tableViewA indexPathsForSelectedRows] lastObject];

    NSString *grabTicker = [[homeJson objectAtIndex:indexPathA.row]objectForKey:@"returnId"];




    [[segue destinationViewController] setGrabTicker:grabTicker];


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the segue from the view controller itself to the destination view controller by ctrl dragging from the view controller icon below the view layout to the destination view controller.

Name the segue.

Use the segue:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"alertDetail" sender:indexPath];
}
```

Then your prepareForSegue looks like:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"alertDetail"]) {
        NSString *grabTicker = [[homeJson objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"returnId"];

        [[segue destinationViewController] setGrabTicker:grabTicker];
    }
}
```

Of course, all of this begs the question of why you're not just doing the cell layout as a prototype cell in a storyboard, but there ya go.

Comment: This sounds like the perfect solution.  Not a direct answer to the question, but exactly what I was hoping to hear.  Could you elaborate on #3?  Where is didSelectCell?  I am using prepareForSegue method, would this go here?  I'm adding the code above...

Comment: Wow!  It works...  Thank you so much.  This is exactly what I was hoping for but so many threads suggest it's not possible without a prototype cell.  Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Change the class of the prototype cell in your storyboard to the subclass of the cell you use in code. Make sure to set the prototype cell's type to custom so that it doesn't replace your cell's view hierarchy.

(As a side note, remember to add your views to the `contentView` of the cell, not directly to the cell itself!)

Comment: By type to custom, do you mean Style -> custom under 'Attributes Inspector' ?

Comment: Yes. This tells interface builder to leave the content view empty.

Comment: Still not tapping through to the destination view.  With the storyboard, do I need to connect this new prototype cell to any outlets / responders / etc.?

Comment: No, since you setup all your views in code. Specifying the subclass should suffice.